# How do i use array to display all 5 information of batsman

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, oop

this is the question:Create an array of object to display the information of five batsmen.what i encountered is after compiling it displays same information 5 times how do i fix that.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class batsman{
private:
    string first_n;
    string last_n;
    int runs_made;
    int no_of_fours;
    int no_of_sixes;
    int i;  //do i need to insert [] to initialize arrays
public:
    void getvalue(){
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){ //its displaying only one information five times
        
        cout<<"Enter first name of a batsman"<<endl;
        cin>>first_n;
        cout<<"Enter last name of a batsman"<<endl;
        cin>>last_n;
        cout<<"number of runs made"<<endl;
        cin>>runs_made;
        cout<<"Number of fours"<<endl;
        cin>>no_of_fours;
        cout<<"Number of sixes"<<endl;
        cin>>no_of_sixes;
    }
    }
    
     void display(){
        for(i=0;i<5;i++){ //how do i use array to diaplay all 5 information
         
        cout<<"...Batsman Information..."<<endl;
        cout<<"Name:"<<first_n<<last_n<<endl; /*also how do i give white space in between first and last name.*/
        cout<<"Total runs:"<<runs_made<<endl;
        cout<<"Total fours:"<<no_of_fours<<endl;
        cout<<"Total sixes:"<<no_of_sixes<<endl;
    }
        
    }
    
 };
int main(){
batsman b;
b.getvalue();
b.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason that it display same information 5 times is that in `getvalue` function you are looping 5 time and in every loop you are get value from user and after that store those value in some variable but in every loop you are store value in same variable therefore you are override previous stored value so in order to do this i encourage you to use `std::vector` and in loop when you got value from user store those values in `std::vector` with `push_back` method example:

```
std::vector<std::string> first_names;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  std::string local_first_name;
  std::cin >> local_first_name;
  first_names.push_back(local_first_name);
}
```

and display every item of vector with:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  std::cout << first_names.at(i);
}
```

for your second question you can print white space between first_name and last name like this:

```
std::cout << first_name << " " << last_name << std::endl;
```

more information about std::vector [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).